# https://login.salesforce.com/id/keys is returning random results

Tags: rest-api, oauth2, authentication

I build a third-party application that integrates with Salesforce using the REST API (connected app). We hit `/services/oauth2/token` to get a token for the user, then we verify the token using the associated RSA key from `https://login.salesforce.com/id/keys`. Here's the problem. In the past two months, we've started to get intermittent failures. You'll notice if you go to https://login.salesforce.com/id/keys and then refresh the page a couple times, you get random responses. You can tell by looking at the `"kid"` fields in the JSON. Often `"kid": "222"` is not present, for instance.

Is this expected from this endpoint? I would assume not seeing as we only started getting errors from this in the past two months when we've had this integration for a couple years.

I've also noticed that hitting the `/id/keys` endpoint from an org-specific domain like https://na49.lightning.force.com/id/keys always returns a consistent result, but never includes `"kid": "228"` like `https://login.salesforce.com/id/keys` sometimes does.

So is it safe to use the org-specific domain since it's consistent? Or does my server need to handle the inconsistency in order to support `"kid": "228"`?

Answer (score 1):

There's a chain of custody you have to follow when retrieving the public key: the `iss` (Issuer) of the `id_token` you're trying to verify determines the [location of the keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57085381/how-does-jwt-io-already-know-my-public-key). By default, the issuer will be `login.salesforce.com` for a production org but (for example) a community hosted in the same org will have a different issuer.

If the `id_token` issued by SF does not have a corresponding public key in the JSON Web Key Set (JWKS), then you can't validate the signature on the token and therefore cannot rely on this token. (Correspondence is established via `kid`). As far as your client acting in the capacity of OpenID Connect Relying Party is concerned, when token validation fails not using this token is your only app-level, programmatic recourse.

You could complain to Salesforce that you can't validate `id_token` due to a missing key. We haven't seen such a scenario but if you have evidence of this, please let Salesforce know by opening a support case.